# How fast does my connection need be to play World of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I've got a bad connection and I would like to know if I can play WoW without experiencing major problems.

This is my connection:

Ping: 30 ms

Download: 3.21 Mbps

Upload: 1.51 Mbps

Comment: 3.21 is enough fasts

Comment: Thanks, Do you think my connection is good to play League of legend, Minecraft, Diablo too?

Comment: If you get a ping of 30 in any game you should be good to go. To actually answer this, it would depend on your location, the server you're on, etc. If I were you I would simply play these games to test it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The product specs for WoW say that it works with 56K modems, so your bandwidth should be fine.

In my firsthand experience, if I'm experiencing lag it's related to packet loss. I won't detail how to fix that since it's a long IT troubleshooting process, but if you go to pingtest.net and your "Jitter" is fairly low you should be okay.

Comment: Lag can also be the computer itself.  If you have a dying hard drive that is generating read/write errors, the computer is overheating, or various performance degrading problems, then you'll experience "lag".

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure on the computer speed you need, but you can set the graphics and other settings to allow yourself to play without slowdown. Hit escape when you get into azeroth-and select System first. There is a preset for graphics here called Ultra. Try setting it to that, go to orgimmar or stormwind, then spam your aoe spells while standing next to as many people as possible. If your spell/sound/screen are flowing smoothly, then you have a really good PC and connection, if not, set your Ultra graphics to high, and repeat the process. If you have to play on low, look at some of the other settings-anything that improves framerate or processing speed is good.

Using a 6 core processor, high speed internet, and an above average graphics card might not be enough to reach the ultra graphics-as you can still get slowdown.  Based off what you asked though, it sounds like want lower settings in order to enjoy the game.

Comment: Turning down settings does nothing at all for bandwidth usage.

Comment: "I've a bad connection and I would like to know if I can to play without big problems to World or warcraft." Thank you for letting me know in elitist speak that we are suddenly talking about bandwith instead of settings. He is asking if he can play without big problems in spite of his connection. Which, as my original answer stated can be done regardless of your connection

Comment: I don't know how else you can interpret that.  Turning down settings has nothing to do with bandwidth or your connection.  This offers zero useful information to actually help the asker.